# JS How is lookup list so much faster for searching for elements?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search

Let's say you want to search for a match between two arrays.
You could loop through both array and find a match. This is O(N*M) though.

I've found another option is to create a lookuplist.

How is it that using a lookuplist (simple Object mapping dictionary) is much faster to search for an element than using a search algorithm?

i.e.

```
const map {
  hundreds of keys to hundreds of values
}
```

One can simply find the value of a foo key by doing the below

`map['foo'] = bar`.

As opposed to multiple loops or using something like `_.filter or _.find`

I understand that the map method would introduce more memory into the equation. But processing-wise it seems to scale nicely. What is it with hashes that make searching so fast? Isn't a full-scan of all keys still needed at the end of the day?

Comment: The tasks are different, you're talking about finding a match of _values_ between two arrays, and then getting a value by a _key_ from an object.

Comment: ah, that makes perfect sense. is finding a value from 1 key still in linear time though? Wouldn't it still have to do a full scan.

Comment: Reading a value from an object by a key is O(1), no scanning. It's the same with arrays, you can get a value by an index (`arr[n]`).

Comment: What JavaScript does under the hood is have a mapping from string to bucket (called a hash function).  If the number of buckets is similar to the number of strings, with high probability the string will be in a bucket with very few strings and a search of the bucket will be fast.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table for more.

Comment: If your hash gets too big, they resize it.  Meaning that they create a bigger space with more buckets and move everything.  This is very expensive, but also very rare.  And as a result the overhead of doing this occasionally is fixed per element.